# "bad option -readonly" error when trying to run Qsim on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, vhdl, verilog

I'm trying to test my Verilog code on Qsim. When I open Qsim and try to open my project, it gives me an error of `bad option "-readonly": must be -group, -owner, or -permissions`. I don't know what this error means, and I don't know how to fix it. If anyone could help me it would be amazing.

I'm on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 computer using Quartus 2 v12.0SP2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little googling said it's likely a TCL script error message.  Add QSIM and quotes
and I got a hit but could access the Altera Forum archives (something about
a database error).

I got this out of google cache [Qsim Linux? [Archive] - Altera Forums](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-32358.html .

```
gPaiva
October 20th, 2011, 08:53 PM
Hi i am new to FPGAs , and tried to install it on linux , quartus runs fine,
but i need a simulation . i tried type at shell quartus_sh -qsim , the qsim 
opened but when i try open a project i get this result:

img820.imageshack.us/img820/673/capturadetelaf.png (not allowed to post 
links, lol :()

if u cant see the image it says : bad option "-readonly": must be -group, 
-owner or -permissions

...

AnthonyWBrown
March 30th, 2012, 09:25 AM
Have you found a cure for this yet?

Actually, I found a workaround. Looks like there is a syntax problem with 
the tcl script, it appears to try to clear the -readonly permissions on
the various files. My knowledge of tcl would fit on the head of a pin, but 
according to the tcl documentation I found you can only do that on a Mac. 
Linux allows you to do -owner and -group and -permissions, which makes 
sense for linux filesystems, I guess. Anyhow, hence the error.

This -readonly thing is done in several places, but the one that causes the
problem you describe is in the "qsim:open_project" procedure. If you edit 
the file quartus/common/tcl/apps/qsim/qsim_script.tcl and go down to line 
1413 or so you should find:

file attributes db -readonly 0

comment this out by putting a # in front and save it and you're good to go. 
If you feel keen, you could find the other places the file attributes 
-readonly function is called and comment them out, too. If you were feeling 
super keen, you could fix the tcl to use something cross-platform compatible
and submit a patch to Altera.....

Hope this helps.

A/B

nigelg
August 17th, 2012, 07:04 AM
thanks for the workaround, just got clobbered by it.

something like this works as a patch, a bit long winded.

#######################################
set my_plat [lindex $tcl_platform(os) 0]
if {[string equal $my_plat "Linux"]} {
if {[file writable db] == 0} {
# not writable so get current permissions
set myperms [file attributes db -permissions]
#set user write permissions leaving rest unchanged
set myperms [expr $myperms | 0200]
file attributes db -permissions $myperms
}

} else {
# hopefully it's windoze
file attributes db -readonly 0
}
########################################

My tcl is fairly limited so there are probably better ways to do it.

nigelg
August 17th, 2012, 07:16 AM
oops, wrong draft,

set myperms [expr $myperms | 0200]

should read
set myperms [expr $myperms + 0200]

haulisson
September 18th, 2012, 03:46 PM
Hi guys,

Its solutions were very ingenious, but I do not know much Tcl script. So,
could someone tell where I put this patch proposed by nigelg.

Best Regards

nigelg
October 15th, 2012, 08:13 AM
Hi,

find the lines containing

file attributes db -readonly 0

as described in an earlier post, comment out the line and replace with the
correct version of my patch. You will need to do this for each original 
occurence of the line.

HTH
Nigel
```

Seems like there aren't a lot of Linux users for QSIM, or Altera expects them to
be self sufficient.  (And quoting the forum posts as code was the easier than totally
reformatting them).

Running http://wiki.sj.ifsc.edu.br/wiki/index.php/Uso_do_Quartus_II_nos_Labs_do_IFSC through google translate gives us another hit for the same Altera Forum thread with a slightly different fix:

### Fix BUG in Qsim.

```
When installing Qsim an error (bad option "-readonly": must be-group, or-permissions-owner) can occur when opening the project file generated in Quartus II. The fix is to open the file quartus / common / tcl / apps / Qsim / qsim_script.tcl and comment lines:

  699 # file attributes $ Qsim :: project_dir / Qsim / $ Qsim :: project_name.sim.vwf-readonly 1
  812 # file attributes $ Qsim :: project_dir / Qsim / $ Qsim :: project_name.sim.vwf-readonly 1
 1413 # file attributes db-readonly 0

SOURCE: http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-32358.html
```

Comment: And both links in the answer now work.  Didn't take too long to notice their server wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the second fix first because it seemed easier and it fixed my problem completely. You have to give yourself write permissions to be able to comment those lines, but that was no issue. Thank you :)